# Get multiple values from inputs in a live way JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have two inputs which are datepickers thanks [to this](https://github.com/uxsolutions/bootstrap-datepicker)

```html
<div class="col-6">
  <input type="text" class="dateselect startDateJq "   required="required"/>
</div>
<div class="col-6">
 <input type="text" class="dateselect  endDateJq"  required="required"/>
</div>
```

and now im trying to get the dates in string format in a live way (not onload or keyup, when user picked or changed his date the variable changes) with JQ to calculate the price for the customer based on the difference between two dates like this.

```js
 $('.startDateJq, .endDateJq').on("input", function(){
      var a = ($(".startDateJq").val());
      var b = ($(".endDateJq").val());
 });
```

but as you can guess it's not working at all. I will calculate the difference thanks to moment js but firstly i need this to work

Comment: `bind` is deprecated.  You should be using `on` instead.

Comment: And your `#endDateJq` does not have a `endDateJq` class on it.  Why do you need both ids and classes?

Comment: And if you don't like key-up, or input find here what you need: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp (key-up is live as it gets, don't understand whats wrong with it)... try on change...

Comment: @Taplar yeah that was a typo because i was checking something and didn't ctrl+z all the way up

Comment: Why is the type attribute value text?

Comment: As you are already using `bootstrap-datepicker` you may need to listen on its 'changed' event. Guessing `input` will likely not be triggered. [https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/events.html#changedate)

Comment: @SleekGeek because i'm using the bootstrap builded datepicker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your questions correctly, I would advise you to listen to change in value. See the example below.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#startDateJq, #endDateJq').on("change", function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var a = new Date($(".dateselect").val());
      var b = new Date($(".dateselect1").val());
      var diff = (b - a);
      alert(diff / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24 + " Day(s)");
    }, 1000); // A litle delay to wait for both values
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-6">
  <input type="date" class="dateselect" id='startDateJq ' required="required" />
</div>
<div class="col-6">
  <input type="date" class="dateselect1" id='endDateJq' required="required" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Zhonk was right the input wasn't triggered at all this will work

```js
  $('.dateselect').datepicker()
    .on('changeDate', function() {
        var a = ($(".startDateJq").val());
        console.log(a)
    });
```